# How to fill values in column by comparison values from another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe contains some columns. Column 'model' contains some same values but column 'power' is not full. How can I fill all NaN-values in 'power' by same 'model' from another row?

```
display(df)

   model     power      ...
0      A       100      ...
1      B       200      ...
2      A       NaN      ...
3      C       300      ...
4      B       NaN      ...
```

The expected result is like this:

```
   model     power      ...
0      A       100      ...
1      B       200      ...
2      A       100      ...
3      C       300      ...
4      B       200      ...
```

I created new dataframe 'models_with_power' which contains unique 'model' with filled 'power'. But I don't know what to do next:

```
temp_df = df[df['power'].isnull() == False]

models_with_power = pd.DataFrame({'model':temp_df['model'].unique()})

models_with_power = models_with_power.merge(temp_df, on='name', how='right')
```

Comment: Is `df["new_power"] = df.groupby("model").power.ffill()` working?

Comment: This should work

Answer (score 1):

Would not forward fill do the job?

```py
dataf['power'] = dataf.groupby('model')['power'].transform(lambda d: d.ffill())
```

Or simpler per @Mustafa Aydın

```py
# credit to
dataf["power"] = dataf.groupby("model").power.ffill()
```

Complete working code: Filling forward and backward

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


dataf = pd.DataFrame(
{
 'model':list('ABACB'),
 'power':[100, 200, np.nan, 300, np.nan]
})

# first fill foward with previous value of the same group
# then fill backwards

dataf['power'] = dataf.groupby('model')['power'].transform(lambda d: d.ffill().bfill())
                                                  
print(dataf)
```